# How to send file from action to next action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in RoR.

I want to make that logic:

1. User `upload` `xml` or `csv` file from `/home (static_pages#home)` and send it to `elms#el_select`
2. If file is `xml` and file contain more than one element I want to show page to user so him choose which element he want to show
3. If file is `csv` or `xml` with one element I want to show result page

So here is two `use-cases`:

```
- choose file - view results
- choose file - choose element - view results
```

In second case I `upload` file in `static_pages#home`, send it to `elms#el_select` and I don't know how to send it from `elms#el_select` to result page.

In first case I don't know how to skip page rendering and send file to another controller

Comment: `render: :nothing true`. this will render nothing and if you want to go to another action simply use `redirect_to`

Comment: Is there any way to send file as a parameter?

Comment: do you have any view between the two `methods` ?

Comment: you can temporarily store file and then pass file name and again read that file because if possible i don't think it is good approach to send file.

Comment: ok then in first method store your file temporary and get its name and pass it to next method and in next method read the file using its name

Comment: If I store file in tmp and send filename is there any way to catch event if user close page on second step or just lose internet connection so application will delete it?

Comment: i don't have knowledge about that but for that purpose you can add `cron job` using `whenever gem`

Comment: May be is there something like session_internal_storage on server side where I can store file, get id and it will deleted when session ends?

Comment: I google it : MemCacheStore - Stores the data in MemCache.
ActiveRecordStore - Stores the data in a database using Active Record. I think this is the one I'm looking for

Comment: Good Luck. At least I could help you out finding your way

Comment: I've think about it and decide to change application architecture: add model for storing files and link files to model with elements, so I will do app more MVC way and do it more simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found answer on my question:

```
@key = SecureRandom.uuid
Rails.cache.write(@key, @file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Controllers do not store files for up/download or any other data. They just manipulating with instances of their models (with their behaviour). So, if I have understand your question in the right way, the order may be next:

1. `StatiPagesController` take the file from user and store it somewhere (/tmp or smth.) if the file is valid;
2. `ElmsController` take the file from storage and `render` the proper view (or `redirect_to` proper view if such already exist).

Comment: Can I store file data in class instance variable or smth? Is there any way to send filename in parameters or smth that can help me identify exactly what file this user upload?